# WSO2 Idenity, XACML Simple Editor, Try It tool - Rules Evaluation

Tags: wso2, editor, identity, xacml, wso2-identity-server

I wrote a basic test case with XACML using the Simple Editor tool.

My rule:  "Only doctor can access medical records"

When using the role name "admin", all works OK and the answer from the request is "permit". 
Case I update the role, both in the policy and request and set it to the value:  "doctor", then the rules engine returns a erroneous "deny". For testing, I've also recorded a user role name with the value "doctor", which is the desired value and added one ID under the WSO2 console.

Why XACML under WSO2 constantly denies any evaluation request when using other role then "doctor"?  (see the resulting policy and request statements below)

**Policy**

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="MedicalRecords" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>doctors</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">MedicalRecords</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="Rule-1">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:any-of">
            <Function FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal"/>
            <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="Deny-Rule"/>
</Policy>
```

**Request**

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">MedicalRecords</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

Thanks for feedback and support.

Regards, 
Claude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have added `http://wso2.org/claims/role` as the AttributeId for the subject, following should be your XACML request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
      <Attribute AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" IncludeInResult="false">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">doctor</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
   <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
      <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
         <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">MedicalRecords</AttributeValue>
      </Attribute>
   </Attributes>
</Request>
```

in XAML values are matches against AttributeId, you must use the same AttributeId. Butm you have used `urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id` as the AttributeId in the request.

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly. Was not aware about the need to manually adjust the AttributeId in the request. Would be nice if the tool could build a template. Yet, another doubt from a beginner:  Is there any trace command that allows to track the reasoning steps of the rules engine, that generates the final outcome:  "Permit", "Deny" or "Not applicable"  within the flow of a policy?

Comment: You can add `log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement=DEBUG' into <IS_HOME>/repository/conf/log4j.properties. So you can see the reason. You don't need add the AttributeId manually, if you don't modify the policy and added that custom AttributeId.